# Python Cmd module, subclassing issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to work out what's not working in this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cmd

class My_class (cmd.Cmd):
    """docstring for Twitter_handler"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(My_class, self).__init__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_handler = My_class()
```

Here's the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    my_handler = My_class()
  File "main.py", line 9, in __init__
    super(My_class, self).__init__()
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

If I change the superclass of "My_class" to an object it works fine. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[super()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) only works for [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle)

Answer (score 8):

cmd.Cmd is not a new style class in Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7.

Note that your code does *not* raise an exception in Python 3.0.

Comment: Is that because the cmd module is rewritten in Python 3?

Comment: Nope. It's because in Python 3.0 all classes are "new style classes".

Comment: (In fact, a diff between 2.5's and 3.0's cmd.py will show you that very few changes were made between those versions.)

Comment: I wonder, could you change 'class Cmd:' in cmd.py to 'class Cmd(object)' and expect no problems?

Comment: It would probably work. But you'd have the only python 2.x installation on earth with a new-style Cmd class... Don't let any code you ship depend on that :)

Answer (score 2):

So if [super()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) doesn't work use :

```
import cmd

class My_class(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `super()` if your `MyClass` extends `object`. This works even though the `cmd.Cmd` module is *not* a new-style class. Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cmd

class My_class (cmd.Cmd, object):
    """docstring for Twitter_handler"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(My_class, self).__init__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_handler = My_class()
```

Comment: This works for me as well.  Can anyone weigh in on any weird side-effects in Py2 or Py3?