# Initialise matrix in python

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python list problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959744/python-list-problem)

I try to initialise a matrix in python. 
First I did this:

```
>>> M=[[0]*4]*4
```

But here is my probleme, every line is changing when I change the first one:

```
>>> M
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> M[1][1]=1
>>> M
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

So I did it this way:

```
>>> M= [ [ 0 for i in range(4) ] for j in range(4) ]
```

And ut works fine:

```
>>> M
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> M[1][1]=1
>>> M
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

My question is:

What these two expressions really mean ? ans why the first one is behaving this way ?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `a` is some python object. Then `[a] * 4` is equivalent to [a, a, a, a]. What this means depends on whether `a` is *mutable* or not. Numbers, strings and tuples are not, so if `a` is one of these kinds of objects (`0` in your example), then you get 4 independently changeable copies. Lists, dictionaries and sets are mutable, and in this case you just get 4 references to the same object, in your case the list `[0] * 4`. Exploiting this knowledge, you'll see that you can do this:

```
M = [[0] * 4 for i in range(4)]
```

and get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

When you multiply those lists, Python is copying them by reference rather than creating entirely new objects.

A simple example might help, showing what happens with copy by reference:

```
>>> pie = ['apple', 'cherry', 'pecan']
>>> pie_copy = pie
>>> pie_copy[0] = 'banana'
>>> pie
['banana', 'cherry', 'pecan']
>>> pie is pie_copy
True
>>> new_pie = ['banana', 'cherry', 'pecan']
>>> pie is new_pie
False
```

In the same way that pie_copy and pie point to the same list, when building lists by multiplying, all the copies point to the same list.

In your second snippet using `range()` and list comprehensions, you aren't taking a single list and copying it several times; each iteration in the comprehension is creating a new list, so you don't suffer from the same copy by reference problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because here `M=[[0]*4]*4`
You create a links on objects.

It's the similar as

```
>>> a = [0, 0, 0]
>>> b = [a,a,a]
>>> b
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[1] = 1
>>> b
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
>>>
```

**UPD** links I meant references, sorry if little confusing