# Python array weird behavior

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange behavior of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191749/strange-behavior-of-lists-in-python)

I am attempting to initialize a 6 by 6 2D array of None. Here is what I do:

```
arr = [[None]*6]*6
```

Then I attempt to insert some values as follows:

```
arr[2][0] = arr[2][1] = 0
```

Which instead of changing the values of (2,0) and (2,1) to 0 and keeping the rest of the array full of None, it changes all the columns 0 and 1 to 0.

Full example:

```
>>> arr = [[None]*6]*6
>>> arr
[[None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None]]

>>> arr[2][0] = arr[2][1] = 0
>>> arr
[[0, 0, None, None, None, None], [0, 0, None, None, None, None], [0, 0, None, None, None, None], [0, 0, None, None, None, None], [0, 0, None, None, None, None], [0, 0, None, None, None, None]]
```

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

p.s. my use of the phrase 'weird behavior' implies weird to me, not python messing up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `[None]*6`, a list of six `None` values is created. When you multiply *that* by `6`, it's six copies of the *same* list that you get. So modifying one row will also modify all the other rows in the same way.

You can work around this behaviour by doing this (or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python) for alternatives):

```
arr = [[None]*6 for i in xrange(6)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You're making an array with 6 references to the original 6-element array, but you need to have 6 different arrays.

Try

```
[[None]*6 for i in range(6)]
```

That will create 6 different arrays.

Comment: if [[0]*5] is a multiplication of the original element, then why that does not apply to [0]*5 ?