# Issue while modifying elements of nested list in Python

Tags: python, list

In this code, I was expecting that `list A` will have the same value even if I assign it to another `temp` variable and then print the argument `A` using the function `foo`. However, if A was a scalar e.g. `A=3` then the value of `A` remains the same even after calling `foo`.

Where am I going wrong? Is there a problem in the scope of variables? I found some related [Strange behavior of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191749/strange-behavior-of-lists-in-python) answer but couldn't figure out a fix for my problem.

```
A = [ [ 0 for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]

def foo(input):

    temp= input
    temp[0][0]=12
    print(input)

print(A)
answer = foo(A)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[12, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Try to print `answer`

Comment: @Anwarvic, that outputs `None`. `temp` and `input` point to same object, so if you change one that reflects in the other. Btw, don't name as `input`.

Comment: Your code will fail with `A = 3` on `temp[0][0]`, as `temp` would be `3` by this time. You should have a look at  https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of input, use the `.copy` this will make a copy of the array and assign new addresses to temp, what you do is shallow copying, where temp = input, just copies the address of the input array to temp, rather than making a copy of the list.

So you may either do `foo(A.copy())` or `temp=input.copy()` also note input is not a good name since it is already assigned to a python function, use something like foo_arg or something

Comment: Thanks! I used "deepcopy" from copy library, it served my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please this, I used **deepcopy**

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy

A = [ [ 0 for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]

def foo(input):

    temp = deepcopy(input)
    temp[0][0]=12
    return temp

print('origin', A)
answer = foo(A)
print('after', A)
print('result', answer)
```

Result:

```
origin [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
after [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
result [[12, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I also found a good resource over here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/