# LISTS in python anamolous behavior with reference to single dimension lists

Tags: python, list

```
a = [0]*4
a[0]= 1
print(a)
```

Output is [1,0,0,0] while it should be [1,1,1,1] according to the behavior of lists explained in [Strange behavior of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191749/strange-behavior-of-lists-in-python) which says that * creates references to the object and not copy of values.
Please explain

Comment: C.f. `a = [[0]] * 4; a[0][0] = 1`

Comment: Replicating a number does not have the same problems as replicating a list (or other mutable object).  You can't change a number in-place, you can only replace it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, using the repetition operator, `*`, creates multiple references to the objects in the list. However, `a[0] = 1` **does not modify those objects**, it *modifies the list*.

If you *could* modify the objects in the list (you cannot, in this case, because `int` objects are immutable), and then you did modify those objects, then you would see the same behavior.

Note, even if you use `a[0] = <something>` with mutable objects, it won't behave that way:

```
>>> x = [[]]*3
>>> x
[[], [], []]
>>> x[0] = [1] # modify the list
>>> x
[[1], [], []]
```

You have to *actually modify the object inside the list*:

```
>>> x = [[]]*3
>>> x
[[], [], []]
>>> x[0].append(1) # modify the in the list
>>> x
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

The fundamental distinction you are missing is the difference between modifying the list itself versus the objects inside the list.

Note, also, `list` objects *do not have a dimension*.