# Replacing things in 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to make a connect 4 board that is of any size, here is the code:

```
row = [] 
board = [] 
empty = "-" 
  
numOfRows = int(input("Rows: ")) 
numOfCs = int(input("Columns: ")) 
  
for i in range(0, numOfCs): 
    row.append(empty) 
     
for i in range(0, numOfRows): 
    board.append(row) 
  

print(board)

board[4][1] = "R"

print(board)
```

And it prints (if the board is big enough) the list, but in for some reason it replaces "R" for all of the columns in the list, how can I make it only replace the singular value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange behavior of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191749/strange-behavior-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: You added the same list `row` into `board` multiple times.