# Changing a particular element in a 2-D list in python

Tags: python, list

I have the following code:

```
a=[[0]*2]*3

print a


a[1][1]=2
print a
```

the output is:

```
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
[[0,2],[0,2],[0,2]]
```

Why is it changing all the elements of the list?

Shouldn't the output be:

```
[[0,0],[0,2],[0,0]]
```

What needs to be done if I just want to change one of the element?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python list problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959744/python-list-problem)

Answer (score 3):

When you do `[0] * 2`, this results in the list `[0, 0]`. When you multiply that by 3, you're creating a list with three *references* to that list. You probably want to do this instead:

```
a = [[0] * 2 for _ in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem many times and it is frustrating.

When you do this:

```
a = [[0] * 2] * 3
```

You create a list `[0, 0]` and pass its reference thrice to form `a`. Those cloned lists are just references to an original list object. When you modify one, you modify the original and all the rest get modified as well.

The solution is pretty simple:

```
a = [[0 for j in range(2)] for i in range(3)]
```

Instead of passing a list by reference, you create a new one each time.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it changing all the elements of the list?

Because they are all the same element.

> What needs to be done if I just want to change one of the element?

You need to make a list that contains three **different** instances of `[0, 0]`.

Multiplying a list makes a list that refers to the same things multiple times.

Try, for example, `[[0] * 2 for _ in range(3)]`.

The reason there is no problem with `[0] * 2` is that the fact that both elements are "the same `0`" doesn't matter; `0` is `0`, and can't be changed. Writing `a[0][0] = 1` **replaces** the 0, but **modifies** the `[0, 0]` containing that `0` (by virtue of replacing the `0`).