# incrementing elements of 2d list in python

Tags: python, list

I've noticed something strange when trying to implement elements of a 2d list in python.  Here is my code

```
n_dk=2*[5*[0]]
n_dk[0][0]+=1
print n_dk
```

I would expect the output to be

```
[[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

but the actual output is

```
[[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0]]
```

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.  btw I used a numpy array instead and it worked the way I wanted it to.

Comment: This question is asked *many* times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959744/python-list-problem