# List repetition and memory

Tags: python, list, memory-management

Consider this code:

```
lst = [['a']*5]*4
lst[1][1] = '*'
```

And this code:

```
lst= [['a'] * 5 for i in range(4)]
lst[1][1] = '*'
```

What makes them different?

Thanks

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Python List Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959744/python-list-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you are not creating four lists with 5 `a`s in them. Instead, you are creating 4 lists which point to the same list with 5 `a`s in it. So, you change one, the effect is seen in all others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the same objects:

```
>>> lst = [['a']*2]*2
>>> map(id, lst)
[60543624, 60543624]
>>> lst[0] is lst[1]
True
```