# Creating 2D jagged list by specifying lengths of rows

Tags: python

I have a list of integers `x`, and I want to create a 2D jagged list `y` of zeros, such that the length of row `i` of `y` is determined by element `i` of `x`.

For example:

```
x = [1, 3, 4]
```

Then:

```
y = [[0], [0, 0, 0,], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner:

```
x = [1, 3, 4]
y = [[0]*s for s in x]
```

Now `y` will contain the expected value:

```
y
=> [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension, but you want to [avoid making the sublists using the multiplication operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959744/python-list-problem), e.g.:

```
[0] * 5    # will produce 'undesired' behavior (see the above link)
```

One way to do it would be the following

```
>>> x = [1, 3, 4]
>>> [[0 for _ in range(i)] for i in x]
[[0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Using the `*` operator is a problem only if we reuse the same sublists (example: `[[0, 0]]*2`), if we create a different sublist for each row (as shown in my answer) the problem you describe won't happen