# Multidimension array created, but output not as Expected

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a doubt when i create a multidimentional array with `None` element, i.e.
all elements are having same id but only elements of a single row are changed.

```
def array(a, b):
    none = [None for _ in range(b)]
    return [none for _ in range (a)]
```

So now `arr = array(4, 5)` gives

> [[None, None, None, None, None],  [None, None, None, None, None], 
>   [None, None, None, None, None],  [None, None, None, None, None]]

Now when I do `arr[0][4] = 45` It gives

> [[None, None, None, None, 45],
>   [None, None, None, None, 45],
>   [None,None, None, None, 45],
>   [None, None, None, None, 45]]

Every 4th index value is changed to 45
So I tried

```
def id_array(a, b):
    none = [id(None) for _ in range(b)]
    return [none for _ in range (a)]
```

Now `id_arr = id_array(4, 5)`

> [[138022184, 138022184, 138022184, 138022184, 138022184],  [138022184,
>   138022184, 138022184, 138022184, 138022184],  [138022184, 138022184,
>   138022184, 138022184, 138022184],  [138022184, 138022184, 138022184,
>   138022184, 138022184]]

i.e. every value has same `id` so while doing `arr[0][4] = 45` shouldn't every value of arr change to 45 because everyone has same `id` and why only 4th index of every row being changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959744/python-list-problem)

Comment: I know it create duplicate of same list, I was confused about same `id`, and above question doesnt clearify that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reusing the same `none` list for every element you append to your return value, when you want each one to be distinct. That's why updates to `none` via one index are reflected across all others — because you are  editing only a single list, even though you may have multiple references to it.

The way to remedy this behavior is to simply place the first comprehension inside the second:

```
def array(a, b):
    return [[None for _ in range(b)] for _ in range (a)]
```

Comment: Yes but every element is having same id, why is only the given index value being changed of every row

Comment: Each integer `id` is at a distinct position in the list, and since such primitive numeric types are passed by value, changing the value at one index does not trigger any changes in other places. Only the `none` list reference is reused &#x2014; each `id` is an int with its own place in memory.

Comment: @Bijoy yes but more importantly the list ids are the same in your example. So when you edit the list arr[0] you edit all lists, since they are the same.

Comment: ohh so while changing both `id` and the position of the `element` in the list is checked, am i right

Comment: @greole Exactly. This is where reusing references becomes problematic, because for the vast majority of cases this behavior is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are creating a list of identical lists, i.e references to exact same list. If you check the Ids

```
>>> def array(a, b):
       none = [None for _ in range(b)]
       return [none for _ in range (a)]

>>> bs = array(4,5)
>>> [id(b) for b in bs]
[139931681000480, 139931681000480, 139931681000480, 139931681000480]
```

If you `arr[0][4] = 45` you simply changing what the fourth list element points to and not the `None` element self. It becomes more clear if you add a list with distinct id

```
>>> bs.append([1,2,3,4])
>>> bs[0][1] = 1
>>> bs
[[None, 1, None, None, None],
 [None, 1, None, None, None],
 [None, 1, None, None, None],
 [None, 1, None, None, None],
 [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```