# Why doesn't a list append reflect variable changes?

Tags: python-3.x

What's going on here? I'm sure there's a simple solution/fact I'm overlooking. I just can't understand why I can't save values/changes to a NumPy array in this manner.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> memoize = []
>>> parameters = np.array([1, 2]).astype(np.float64)
>>> memoize.append(parameters)
>>> parameters -= np.array([0.5, -0.5])
>>> memoize.append(parameters)
>>> memoize
[array([ 0.5,  2.5]), array([ 0.5,  2.5])]
```

I expected the answer to be

```
[array([ 1.,  2.]), array([ 0.5,  2.5])]
```

Does it have anything to do with a list being mutable ?

Comment: No, it's because you keep appending *the same array*. So you have a list of references to the same array, which is why changes to that array are reflected at every point in the list. Indeed, the problem is that `list.append` **is** reflecting the variable changes!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga man that's tricky. Yes, I see it's updating both elements. Totally unexpected.

Comment: I mean, this is how *everything* in Python works. It's pretty obvious, you are doing `memoize.append(parameters)` over and over again...

Comment: So, try this `mylist = []; x = []`, then `mylist.append(x); mylist.append(x)`. Now `print(mylist)`, then `x.append(42)`, and now try `print(mylist)`

Comment: Anyway, read and understand [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) article by SO legend, Ned Batchelder. I think then it will become obvious.

Comment: I hardly think that's obvious. But thank you for the link, looks like an interesting read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959744/python-list-problem)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that `parameters` is a mutable value, and you're appending multiple references to it while mutating it in place. If you rebound the variable to a new array each time, you wouldn't have an issue.

Try changing

```
parameters -= np.array([0.5, -0.5])
```

to

```
parameters = parameters - np.array([0.5, -0.5])
```

The original version makes an in-place modification to `parameters`. The second version makes a new array with copied data. This is probably a little slower, but it does what you want in this situation.