# i used append() in a loop and for some reason the list changes every time not in the way it should

Tags: python, list

I wrote this code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    lst = []
    current= []
    for i in range(3):
        print(current)
        print(lst)
        lst.append(current)
        print(lst)
        current.append(i)
```

I expected it to print:

```
[]
[]
[[]]
[0]
[[]]
[[],0]
[0,1]
[[],0]
[[],0,[0,1]]
```

But instead it printed:

```
[]
[]
[[]]
[0]
[[0]]
[[0], [0]]
[0, 1]
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

I don't understand why `lst` changes its members into current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of this line `lst.append(current)`, Go with this:

```
from copy import copy

lst.append(copy(current))
```

This problem is that when you append `current` to the `lst` it looks fine, but in the next iteration when you change current and append it again, it will change the previous `current` that you already appended. that's why you see two `[0]` and three `[0, 1]`

take a look at [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959744/python-list-problem) for more clarification.

Also reading [This Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/) will have positive effects of what is copy and types of copies.

Answer (score 0):

unless you are doing a `copy` or `deep copy`, each element of `lst` will point at `current`

```
import copy
lst = []
current= []
for i in range(3):
        print(current)
        print(lst)
        lst.append(copy.copy(current))
        print(lst)
        current.append(i)
```

will print desired result

Answer (score 0):

> **Shallow Copy**
>
> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original.
>
> `lst.append(current[:]) # shallow-copy`
>
> works in both Python 2 and 3.

```
lst = []
current= []
for i in range(3):
    print(current)
    print(lst)
    lst.append(current[:]) # shallow-copy
    print(lst)
    current.append(i)
```