# Return not functioning when applaying booleans

Tags: python, function, return, boolean, return-value

I'm trying something realy easy, but it's not working.

I want to change the boolean value of x, from True to False, but even though I'm returning x with it new value, when I check, it seems that the value never changed.

```
x = True

def example():
    x = False
    return x

example()
print(x)
```

It prints that x is True, and the boolean value of x doesnt change, I think that the problem is the use of the def and return statement, but, clearly I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do one of the followings :

This (recommended) :

```
x = True

def example(x):
    return not x #it will flip the value. if you need it to be always false, change it

x = example(x)
print(x)
```

Or This

```
x = True

def example():
    global x
    x = not x

example()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is thanks to the intricacies of python variable creation, and what you are trying to do is change what python sees as a `global` variable. This is answered in much more depth in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) post but in short, adding the `global` keyword in functions specifying the variables will solve your problem.

```
x = True

def example():
    global x
    x = False
    return x

example()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the variable in the outer scope, you need to explicitly assign to it, like so:

```
x = True

def example():
    return False

x = example()
print(x)
# False
```

In the code you posted, variable `x` in the outer scope is implicitly hidden by variable `x` in the inner scope of function `example`. When the function is done executing, the inner scope `x` goes out of existence, leaving just the outer scope variable `x`, which retains the same value as before.

**SEE ALSO:**
[Python 2.x gotchas and landmines - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4285788/967621)
[Python Scope & the LEGB Rule: Resolving Names in Your Code – Real Python: Using the LEGB Rule for Python Scope](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#using-the-legb-rule-for-python-scope)