# Getting error when I try to print a global variable in a function in Python3

Tags: python, scope, global, variable-assignment, local

In this simple code to learn differences about global and local variable:

```
def sub():
    print(a)
    a="banana"
    print(a)

a="apple" 
sub()
print(a)
```

I am getting an error:

> UnboundLocalError
>
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 5
> 6 a="apple"
> ----> 7 sub()
> 8 print(a)
>
> in sub()
> 1 def sub():
> ----> 2     print(a)
> 3     a="banana"
> 4     print(a)
> 5
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

I am currently understanding that 'a' is a global variable which is declared **outside** a function.

(It is not declared on any function like main() in C)

But why is this error telling me that 'a' is a local variable?

I know if I add `global a` above the  `print(a)` line will solve this error, but I want to know WHY.

Comment: The short version is that when python compiles the function `sub`, it sees that `a` is declared as a variable inside, and shadows the one on the global scope immediately (rather than waiting until the relevant line of code is actually run). Then, when the code does get run, it hasn't been assigned yet, so you get the error.

Comment: it is simply because of the scope of a in your function. The scope starts with the local and then to global. but because you have declared an 'a' within the scope of the function. you will get that error pre-assignment error. which means  it has identified that a exists within the function scope, but just referenced after your print()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python interprets this line: `a="banana"` in the function as the definition of a new, local, variable `a`. This variable in the scope of the function replaces the global variable `a`. Note that `print(a)` (reference to local variable `a`) occurs **before** `a="banana"` (= assignment). Hence you get the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)
[Python gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4285788/967621)
[The 10 Most Common Mistakes That Python Developers Make](https://www.toptal.com/python/top-10-mistakes-that-python-programmers-make)

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks. I forgot that Python doesn't read each line after other like C.

Comment: Actually, most of the time, python will seem to read each line of the source and 'execute' it before looking at the next. In this case the compiler is trying to create byte codes for the function, but realises there is a contradiction. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlgbPLvBs30&t=2305s) video for a brilliant and almost complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is by placing

> print(a)

inside a function sets variable 'a' as a local variable (i.e, local scope) of that function. Ignoring the

> a="apple"

defined outside the function.

And as 'a' value has not been initialized inside the 'sub' function hence its value couldn't be found while executing print(a) hence shows
local variable 'a' referenced before assignment which is exactly what happens in the above case.

FOR SUMMARY

```
def sub():

#     print(a)  #Just comment this and you will understand the difference

## By doing print(a) inside sub function makes sets 'a' as local variable
## whose value has not been initialized
## and as its value couldn't be found while line print(a) executes hence shows
## local variable 'a' referenced before assignment which is exactly what 
##   happens

    a="banana" # a is assigned here 
    print(a)


a="apple" 
sub()
print(a)
```