# How does Python recognize whether a variable in a function is global or local?

Tags: python

I know that a global variable is created in the main scope, and to assign a value to it inside of a function, we need to use the keyword `global`. However, to use it (for example, to print it) inside a function, we don't need to use the keyword `global`. For example:

```
s = 5
def foo1(): 
    print(s)

s = 5
def foo2():
    global s
    s = 6
    print(s)
```

Now I try to do this:

```
s = 5
def foo3():
    print(s)
    s = 'bbb'
    print(s)
```

and I call `foo3()`. I know this is a mistake since I am trying to assign a global  variable inside a function without the use of the keyword `global`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo3
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

However, I'm interested in why the first `print(s)` in `foo3()` is not executed, and I get the error when it tries to run it. How can Python recognize that `s` is a local variable before I even try to apply an assignment (without the keyword `global`)?

I hypothesise that when the function is defined, Python declares all its local variables according to the function code, and therefore it knows before the assignment that `s` is a local variable, and not the global. I tried to find information about this but couldn't (I'm sure there is information that I didn't see).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error when I try to print a global variable in a function in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66225979/getting-error-when-i-try-to-print-a-global-variable-in-a-function-in-python3)

Comment: for better understanding of how python decides to treat if your code is referring a local or global variable, see the [answers] here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function). In short, if variable of same name appears as lvalue without the use of global, then python treats it as local variable to that function.

Comment: Thank you both. I will look at this and see if I understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Answer (score 0):

When the function is defined, Python declares all its local variables according to the function code.

Not all local variables!

In my opinion, Python declares all the *function's* local variables which are seen inside the specific *function* defined or undefined keeping them separate from main variables, when you make it global, the values read or written into the variables are stored onto the main variables directly.