# super() fails with error: TypeError "argument 1 must be type, not classobj" when parent does not inherit from object

Tags: python, object, inheritance, parent, super

I get some error that I can't figure out. Any clue what is wrong with my sample code?

```
class B:
    def meth(self, arg):
        print arg

class C(B):
    def meth(self, arg):
        super(C, self).meth(arg)

print C().meth(1)
```

I got the sample test code from help of 'super' built-in method.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 10, in ?
    print C().meth(1)
  File "./test.py", line 8, in meth
    super(C, self).meth(arg)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

FYI, here is the help(super) from python itself:

```
Help on class super in module __builtin__:

class super(object)
 |  super(type) -> unbound super object
 |  super(type, obj) -> bound super object; requires isinstance(obj, type)
 |  super(type, type2) -> bound super object; requires issubclass(type2, type)
 |  Typical use to call a cooperative superclass method:
 |  class C(B):
 |      def meth(self, arg):
 |          super(C, self).meth(arg)
 |
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python super() raises TypeError ! Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489269/python-super-raises-typeerror-why)

Comment: Meth?? Is that a programming term, or... y'know? Please clarify.

Comment: @Cplusplusplus: probably stands for Method ;-)

Answer (score 379, accepted):

Your problem is that class B is not declared as a "new-style" class.  Change it like so:

```
class B(object):
```

and it will work.

`super()` and all subclass/superclass stuff only works with new-style classes.  I recommend you get in the habit of always typing that `(object)` on any class definition to make sure it is a new-style class.

Old-style classes (also known as "classic" classes) are always of type `classobj`; new-style classes are of type `type`.  This is why you got the error message you saw:

`TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj`

Try this to see for yourself:

```
class OldStyle:
    pass

class NewStyle(object):
    pass

print type(OldStyle)  # prints: <type 'classobj'>

print type(NewStyle) # prints <type 'type'>
```

Note that in Python 3.x, all classes are new-style. You can still use the syntax from the old-style classes but you get a new-style class. So, in Python 3.x you won't have this problem.

Comment: interesting, I found this exact problem running bottle.py (http://bottlepy.org) which throws a similar error (TypeError: must be type, not classobj) running on Py27 but not Py33.

Comment: In Python 3.x, there are no more "old-style" classes.  Code using the "old-style" declaration still declares a "new-style" class, so this error cannot occur in Python 3.x.

Comment: If class B is not available for you to edit, then you must edit class A to not try to use `super()`; class A must be made to work with an "old-style" class, and possibly the best way to do that would be to make class A be itself an "old-style" class.  Of course I recommend just upgrading your whole program to run in Python 3.x, so that all classes will be new-style no matter what you do; if that option is available it's the best option.

Comment: I have the same issue, but my base class is declared like `class B(object):`.  I'm getting this error due to using `@mock.patch('module.B', autospec=B)` just before my test case.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 184):

Also, if you can't change class B, you can fix the error by using multiple inheritance.

```
class B:
    def meth(self, arg):
        print arg

class C(B, object):
    def meth(self, arg):
        super(C, self).meth(arg)

print C().meth(1)
```

Comment: I could not help to leave a comment, this one should be accepted as 'standard' answer.

Comment: For future googlers stuck on Python 2.6: this is the answer you probably want! When you can't change the base class (e.g. you're subclassing a standard library class), this change to your own class fixes super().

Comment: It worked fine to me, Can you somebody explain how it works?

Comment: @subro, this makes your class a "new-style" class (where class object is of type `type`) while still subclassing an "old-style" class (whose class object is of type `classobj`).
`super()` works with new-style classes but not with old-style classes.

Answer (score 25):

If the python version is 3.X, it's okay.

I think your python version is 2.X, the super would work when adding this code

```
__metaclass__ = type
```

so the code is

```
__metaclass__ = type
class B:
    def meth(self, arg):
        print arg
class C(B):
    def meth(self, arg):
        super(C, self).meth(arg)
print C().meth(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

I was also faced by the posted issue when I used python 2.7. It is working very fine with python 3.4

To make it work in python 2.7 I have added the `__metaclass__ = type` attribute at the top of my program and it worked.

`__metaclass__` : It eases the transition from old-style classes and new-style classes.