# Is Tkinter.Canvas a classic class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to know if `Tkinter.Canvas` is a classic or modern Python class, because `super` does not work as expected (for me).

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Say you have `x = tkinter.Canvas` then is `type(x)` giving you `instance`? What do you get if you do `print x`?

Comment: Yes, `Tkinter.Canvas` is an *"old-style"* class, it doesn't inherit from `object` and therefore won't play well with `super` etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inherit from Tkinter.Canvas - calling super leads to error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389918/inherit-from-tkinter-canvas-calling-super-leads-to-error)

Comment: Ok I think it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389918/inherit-from-tkinter-canvas-calling-super-leads-to-error  I did not find it because of the bad search system of SE. @jonrsharpe this is what I searched for.

Comment: @LittleByBlue it's literally the first hit for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tkinter+canvas+super

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Tkinter classes in python 2.x are old style classes.