# Python inheritance add new init on child

Tags: python, inheritance

https://pastebin.com/GyPzN8Yz

I want to initiate and calculate volume from TwoDim class without repeat to define length and wide, and without to make instance of TwoDim but direct create ThreeDim.

```
class TwoDim():
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.square = self.length * self.width

class ThreeDim(TwoDim):
    def __init__(self, height):
        self.height = height
        self.volume = self.square * self.height
```

> I try someting like this, but still not work..
>
> ```
> class TwoDim(): 
>     def __init__(self, length, width): 
>         self.length = length 
>         self.width = width 
>         self.square = self.length * self.width 
>
> class ThreeDim(TwoDim): 
>     def __init__(self, length, width, height): 
>         super().__init__(self, length, width, height) 
>         self.height = height 
>         self.volume = self.square * self.height 
>
> block = ThreeDim(length = 10, width = 5, height = 4)
> ```

Comment: Probably helpful: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#super

Comment: I try someting like this, but still not work.. 
<code>
class TwoDim():
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.square = self.length * self.width

class ThreeDim(TwoDim):
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        super().__init__(self, length, width, height)
        self.height = height
        self.volume = self.square * self.height

block = ThreeDim(length = 10, width = 5, height = 4)
</code>

Comment: `super().__init__(self, length, width, height)` -> `super().__init__(self, length, width)`

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 :

```
class ThreeDim(TwoDim):
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        super().__init__(length, width)
        self.height = height
        self.volume = self.square * self.height
```

Python 2 :

```
class ThreeDim(TwoDim, object):
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        super(ThreeDim, self).__init__(length, width)
        self.height = height
        self.volume = self.square * self.height
```

Or :

```
class TwoDim(object):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.square = self.length * self.width

class ThreeDim(TwoDim):
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        super(ThreeDim, self).__init__(length, width)
        self.height = height
        self.volume = self.square * self.height
```

([classes need to inherit from object to use super()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713038/super-fails-with-error-typeerror-argument-1-must-be-type-not-classobj-when/18392639) and that's one of the reason why python3 syntax is easier.)

Don't forget the self parameter on TwoDim :

```
class TwoDim():
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.square = self.length * self.width
```