# Patching an object in a Factory class yields TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not MagicMock

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, mocking, monkeypatching

I want to mock an object in a Factory and get the error "The error I get is:

> TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not MagicMock.".

I read the post: [super() fails with error: TypeError "argument 1 must be type, not classobj" when parent does not inherit from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713038/super-fails-with-error-typeerror-argument-1-must-be-type-not-classobj-when), but I don't know how I should derive a MagicMock from object.

My Code is the following:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class B():
    pass

class A(B):
    pass


class AFactory:

    def create(self):
        a = A()
        super(A, a).__init__()

with patch('mymain.A'):
    AFactory().create()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not MagicMock
```

What is the reason for this problem? I use a factory for "A", because I can do better integration tests, if I have the super class called separate in a factory.

Comment: What's the point of that call to `super`? Why is it there in the first place? And why do you use a separate `AFactory` class?

Comment: My "A-class" is actually "class Controller(cmd.Cmd)". If I want to do an integration test, I don't want to call the super() of cmd.Cmd, because it will prompt an input. If you have a better suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: You should remove the prompt and find other ways to provide the data to the instance. Or you can mock `input` of course ...