# TypeError Python Class

Tags: python, caffe

I have a library (caffe) that has the following definition:

```
class NetSpec(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetSpec, self).__setattr__('tops', OrderedDict())

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.tops[name] = value

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.tops[name]

    def to_proto(self):
        names = {v: k for k, v in self.tops.iteritems()}
        autonames = {}
        layers = OrderedDict()
        for name, top in self.tops.iteritems():
            top.fn._to_proto(layers, names, autonames)
        net = caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
        net.layer.extend(layers.values())
        return net
```

When I try to call it using `n = caffe.NetSpec()` I get the following error:

```
  File "../../python/caffe/layers.py", line 84, in __init__
    super(NetSpec, self).__setattr__('tops', OrderedDict())

TypeError: must be type, not None
```

I checked [SO-9698614](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698614/super-raises-typeerror-must-be-type-not-classobj-for-new-style-class),[SO-576169](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489269/python-super-raises-typeerror-why?lq=1) and [SO-489269](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489269/python-super-raises-typeerror-why?lq=1) but they did not lead to a solution.  My class is a new type class and I could not see why it was not working.

## Full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-72-694741de221d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/shaunak/caffe-pr2086/examples/wine/classify.py', wdir='/home/shaunak/caffe-pr2086/examples/wine')

  File "/home/shaunak/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/shaunak/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 78, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/shaunak/caffe-pr2086/examples/wine/classify.py", line 26, in <module>
    f.write(str(logreg('examples/hdf5_classification/data/train.txt', 10)))

  File "/home/shaunak/caffe-pr2086/examples/wine/classify.py", line 18, in logreg
    n = caffe.NetSpec()

  File "../../python/caffe/layers.py", line 84, in __init__
    super(NetSpec, self).__setattr__('tops', OrderedDict())

TypeError: must be type, not None
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I rechecked the trace and un-did my changes on the library. The error is still:  `super(NetSpec, self).__setattr__('tops', OrderedDict())` - updating code

Comment: @shaunakde: do you set `NetSpec` to `None` somewhere? Or otherwise run this code when the module is cleared?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - No it gives me error on initialization itself. `def logreg(hdf5, batch_size):
    # logistic regression: data, matrix multiplication, and 2-class softmax loss
    n = caffe.NetSpec()`. Also could you please give me some reference material for this. I am having a hard time following you.

Comment: @VivekSable - What is exactly the problem with my code? I am using the standard example.

Comment: can u print `print caffe.NetSpec` before `n = caffe.NetSpec()` line ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes sory:) I means `print caffe.NetSpec`

Comment: @MartijnPieters - The old traceback was from my tinkering. Apologies.

Comment: @VivekSable: that'd not give enough info either; we don't know if `caffe.NetSpec` is the right global here..

Comment: @VivekSable - print works. I get `<class 'caffe.layers.NetSpec'>`

Comment: @shaunakde: so you import the class from `caffe` but defined it in `caffe.layers` originally. What does `print caffe.layers.NetSpec` give?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - print caffe.layers.NetSpec
`<function layer_fn at 0x7f8f7d8c82a8>`

Comment: @shaunakde: so how did you define this class and what happened afterwards? You are doing something very funky here. Why is `caffe.layers.NetSpec` now a function object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75835/discussion-between-shaunakde-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you managed to bind `NetSpec` to `None` somewhere:

```
>>> super(None, object())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be type, not None
```

The error indicates that the `NetSpec` global is bound to `None`.

You could also bypass the `NetSpec.__setattr__` method by going directly to the instance `__dict__` attribute:

```
class NetSpec(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.__dict__['tops'] = OrderedDict()
```

From the code you shared it could be that this is the culprit:

```
from .layers import layers, params, NetSpec
```

This imports `caffe.layers` but rebinds `caffe.layers` to the `Layers()` instance. This *could* then trigger Python to delete the module again as there are no other references to it yet (depending on when and how the `sys.modules` reference is created), causing all globals to be rebound to `None` (including `NetSpec`).

Comment: I have updated the stack track. it was unfortunately from my tinkering.

Comment: File "../../python/caffe/layers.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.__dict__['tops'] = OrderedDict()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @shaunakde: yes, because **all** your globals are set to `None`. That includes `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters congrats on your new mod position! good luck!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Congrats on becoming a mod. I was not able to fully solve it but I was about to get around by modifying the library. But this is the best possible explanation.  PS: I voted for you :P