# Getting attribute of superclass

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class A(object):
    has_access = True

class B(A):
    @property
    def has_access(self):
        if (condition):
            return True
        else:
            return super(B, self).__getattribute__('has_access')
```

This does not work (goes in an endless loop). Is there any way to access the original value of the inherited object?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class A(object):
    has_access = True

class B(A):
    @property
    def has_access(self):
        if (condition):
            return True
        else:
            return super(B, self).has_access
```

Comment: Says "has no field has_access"

Comment: Can you post your exact code and stack trace? This code works perfectly for me.

Comment: @tdma encountered the same issue. The problem was explained by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/489278/1398531)